# Presumingly simple runtime analysis, need explanation

Tags: algorithm, code-analysis

According to todays lecture, the first loop has a runtime of the order `O(n)`, while the second loop has a runtime of the order `O(log(n))`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // O(n)
    stuff(); // O(1)
}

for (int i = 1; i < n; i*=4) { // O(log(n))
    stuff(); // O(1)
}
```

Could someone please elaborate on why?

Comment: What point are you having trouble with?

Comment: How many times does each loop get run, relative to `n`?

Comment: @Oli I was just curious as to why the runtime of the second loop is of the order O(log(n)). I was hoping someone could break it down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first loop will do a constant time operation exactly `n` times. Therefore it is `O(n)`.

The second loop (starting from `i = 1` not `i = 0`, you had a typo that I fixed) executes its body for `i` set to 1, 4, 16, 64, ... that is, 4^0, 4^1, 4^2, 4^3, ... up until `n`.

`4^k < n` when `k < log_4(n)`. Therefore the body of the second loop executes `O(log(n))` times, because log base 4 and log base e differ by only a constant coefficient.

Comment: ...and the difference between log(n) [common log, base 10] and log-base-4 is just a constant multiplier (log_4(10) or log_10(4); I don't recall at the moment).

Comment: Thanks for the fix! This explains it well.

Comment: @krystah Mark as answered if appropriate.

Comment: Was going to yesterday, but the timer didn't allow me before I had to go. :)

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity is calculated in terms of how the numbers of times all unit time statements in the code are executed as function of n (input size.)

1. `Input size = n` and for loop runs in `O(N)` and stuff runs of `O(N)*O(1)` hence overall `O(N)`
2. for loop runs till `4^k-1 < n` where `k` is number of iterations. Taking `log` on both sides of inequality we get `(k-1)*log4 < logn,  k < logn/log4 +1,  k=O(logn)` because `log4` is constant. Stuff runs in `O(logn)*O(1)` hence overall `O(logn)`